# Print a single string from and an array without brackets

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

So, existing 2 arrays, i tried to:

```
for palabra in palabras:
    for letras in diccionario:
        clave = str(str(palabra) + str(letras)).split('\n')
#many strings because i tried to string, and restring to try if it works also tried without split()
        print clave
```

And its print ['palabra+letras'] (not literally, you know what i mean) with the brackets.

How do I make this not printing all at the same times like i found on others questions?

Comment: I have difficulty to understand what exactly are you trying to do, would you mind to explain it further?

Comment: *not literally, you know what i mean*, no, no we don't know what you mean since we are not mind readers. *like i found on others questions*, what questions? Please include all relevant information in your question so others have proper context when answering.

Comment: `split` returns a list. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I meant that it print ['adolfhitler']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use use `zip` functionality to print pairs of values.

```
list1 = ["1", "2"]
list2 = ["3", "4"]
for pair in zip(list1, list2):
    print i
```

This will print:

```
 ('1', '3') 
 ('2', '4')
```

Please notice that the lists should be at the same size.

Comment: Thats exactly what i dont want, i want to mix word without the brackets

Comment: OK, now that's progress, how about this:
for pair in (list1, list2):
    print pair[0]+pair[1]

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you are facing is printing the chars '[', ']'
You can iterate the list items using `for` and then print it.

Try the following code:

```
 for i in xrange(len(palabras)):
     print palabras[i] + letras[i]
```